# Use Spring Security in Thymeleaf escaped expressions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring-security, thymeleaf

This is possible with `Thymeleaf` 3.0:

```
/*[# th:if="${user.admin}"]*/
    alert('Welcome admin');
/*[/]*/
```

However this does not work:

```
/*[# sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN)"]*/
    alert('Welcome admin');
/*[/]*/
```

Is that really not possible or am I doing something wrong?

I use Spring Security 4.1.

Some background information about escaped expression parsing: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/395

**Edit 1**

Daniel Fernández found a missing single quote in my initial question.

Unfortulately after adding it, it still does not work.

The expression is parsed, since it disappears from the resulting html/javascript.

But document.writeln() is executed even I am not logged in, or even when I am logged in and I change the check to `sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN123')`

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

    /*[# sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"]*/
        document.writeln("ADMIN !!!");
    /*[/]*/

</script>
```

**Edit 2**

This is my workaround [until further notice](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity/issues/42):

Create a method in a `@Service` which does check whether the user has the needed role(s) or not:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UtilService {

    public boolean hasAnyRole(HttpServletRequest req, String... roles) {
        for (final String role : roles) {
            if (req.isUserInRole(role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

And use it like this in the `JavaScript` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

    /*[# th:if="${@utilService.hasAnyRole(#httpServletRequest, 'ROLE_ADMIN')}"]*/
        ...
    /*[/]*/

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a syntax error. There is no closing quote for your role name in your `sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN)"`...

Comment: Indeed. I'll check later this evening and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Btw a demo-app showing the problem is here: https://github.com/yglodt/spring-boot-thymeleaf

Comment: In the demo-app, the link "page3" needs authentication.

Comment: OK, it seems the SpringSecurity dialect is not registering its processors for the text modes (JAVASCRIPT, CSS, TEXT), and it seems like a good idea to do so (they are currently only available for HTML). Would you please registar that on the GitHub issue system of the Thymeleaf - Spring Security dialect?

Answer (score 1):

I went through same problem and 
I just need to update thymeleaf and thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 that help out.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

Here is [a link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8644)

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather control which user or group has access to a particular JS file instead of writing inline JS you can always add the sec:authorize key in the script tags. This way you can encapsulate fields, functionality, and data to a given set of users and keep the pragmatic use of templates throughout your project.

In this case im using the hasAuthority argument as I've attached a group claim to my JWT when a user signs into my web app. You can obviously tailor this to meet your own needs. Tested and works using Spring5 and thymeleaf 3.

Here is what I mean from your HTML.

```
   <html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
    <body></body>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/myJsFile.js}" sec:authorize="${hasAuthority('usersGroup')}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/myOtherJsFile.js}" sec:authorize="${hasAuthority('adminGroup')}"></script>
```

Here is my POM dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I was specifically looking to do this in order to restrict access to particular database fields for editing a table. https://editor.datatables.net/manual/security#Privilege-escalation

Full reference: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html